# Can a database table be indexed on a function of a column?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-indexes

Can a database index be on a *function* of a column, or must it be on precisely what's in the column itself without any change/adjustment/calculation?

Simple example:

If a `transactions` table contains a column that specifies the datetime of the transaction (e.g. `2020-12-13 12:58:59`), if we want to index on just the date (e.g. `2020-12-13`) of the transaction, does that require another column (with just the date) to be created, or can the index be created on a function of the datetime column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres in fact [supports function indices](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html).  For you example, we can define:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON transactions (cast(ts_col AS date));
```

Comment: Awesome knowledge. Do you know if other dbs have this too? Also, do you know if it's considered good practice? (I would reason that it saves a whole column being created, but it may not be worth the trade off in extra complexity in code and perhaps a little more 'work' the db has to do to compute the calculation?

Comment: Oracle also supports them (I think).  As to the efficiency, what you said is on the right track of thinking, and it depends on your data and goals.

Comment: @stevec: In SQL Server and probably MySQL version 8+ tables can have generated columns that can be calculated from the values of other columns from the same row. Given that they are physically stored (that's an option), they can be indexed. Oracle' FBIs use that mechanism under the hood AFAIK, but normally hides these special columns from the user.

Comment: WRT @sticky-bit answer, it's important to differentiate that with a postgres functional index, the data is stored only once, in the index (and not in the heap). If you use a generated column like in MSSQL, you have to store the data twice, once in the heap for the column, and then once in a non-clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. It can even be any expression, including function calls, and use more than one column of the table.

From the documentation of [`CREATE INDEX`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html):

> ```
> CREATE ... INDEX ... ON ... table_name ...
>     ( { ... ( expression ) } ... ) ...
> ```
>
> ...
>
> `expression`
>
> An expression based on one or more columns of the table. The expression usually must be written with surrounding parentheses, as shown in the syntax. However, the parentheses can be omitted if the expression has the form of a function call.